# is it possible to load python module from unicode path on windows?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to understand if it is simply impossible to load a python module from a unicode path, or if there is some trick I am missing. 
This bug report seems to imply that it is not possible:
http://bugs.python.org/issue11619

Goal:
suppose   C:\Users\pkarasev\д    contains  Foo.py  , then I want to do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(str('c:/Users/pkarasev/\xd0\xb3').decode('utf-8')  )
from Foo import *
```

This fails with "cannot find module..." although u'c:/Users/pkarasev/\0433' has been added to my sys.path and 0433 is the correct encoding for д.

note that the str(...).decode(...) method works for things like os.open, but for some reason not for loading modules. Is there a different format for the encoding? Is this action impossible, period? Do I need to use python 3.x instead of 2.7.3 with some different syntax?

edit: cash award is eligible if someone knows a trick to do this (on windows)

Comment: What does: `python -c "import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())"` say about your windows encoding?

Comment: I get cp1252. 

As far as I can tell, the only way to get the module to import is to first do os.chdir( unicode('c:/Users/pkarasev/\xd0\xb3') ), THEN import Foo.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue9425

Comment: ok, I guess the answer is it's impossible; chdir() workaround is tolerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it is either a bug in python for not supporting windows, or a bug in windows for not being sane and using utf-8 encoding. In python27.dll you can step in and see the bogus module paths...

[image]